# Assign value using overloaded subscript operator

Tags: c++, operators, overloading, subscript

I am trying to create custom array indexed from 1 using subscript operator. Getting value works fine, but I have no clue, why assign using subscript operator doesn't work.

```
class CEntry {
public:
  CKey key;
  CValue val;

  CEntry(const CKey& key, const CValue& val) {
    this->key = key;
    this->val = val;
  }

  CEntry& operator= (const CEntry& b) {
    *this = b;
    return *this;
  };
};
```

...

```
class EntriesArray {    
public:
    CEntry **entries;
    int length;

  EntriesArray(int length) {
    this->length = length;
    entries = new CEntry*[length];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < length + 1; i++) {
        entries[i] = NULL;
    }
  };

  CEntry& operator[] (const int index) {
      if (index < 1 || index > length) {
          throw ArrayOutOfBounds();
      }
      return *entries[index - 1];
  };

};
```

Constructs array this way

```
EntriesArray a(5);
```

This works

```
 a.entries[0] = new CEntry(CKey(1), CValue(1));
 cout << a[1].val.value << endl;
```

This doesn't work

```
a[1] = new CEntry(CKey(1), CValue(1));
```

**EDIT:**

Using

```
CEntry *operator=( CEntry *orig)
```

it compiles okey, but gdb stops at

```
No memory available to program now: unsafe to call malloc warning: Unable to restore previously selected frame
```

with backtrace

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at address: 0x00007fff5f3ffff8
0x00000001000013c8 in CEntry::operator= (this=0x0, orig=0x1001008d0) at /Users/seal/Desktop/efa du2_pokus2/efa du2_pokus2/main.cpp:20
20  /Users/seal/Desktop/efa du2_pokus2/efa du2_pokus2/main.cpp: No such file or directory.
in /Users/seal/Desktop/efa du2_pokus2/efa du2_pokus2/main.cpp
```

Comment: XCode says: No viable overloaded '='

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try replacing

```
CEntry& operator[] (const int index) {
    if (index < 1 || index > length) {
        throw ArrayOutOfBounds();
    }
    return *entries[index - 1];
};
```

with

```
void Add(const int index, CEntry *pEntry) {
    if (index < 1 || index > length) {
        throw ArrayOutOfBounds();
    }
    entries[index - 1] = pEntry;
};
```

but since you are now storing references to objects allocated on the heap (with new) you will need a destructor `~EntriesArray()` to delete them all.

Comment: Yeah, this could be solution, but I would have to create getter as well, I guess.

Comment: I was expecting a way to do it like the std::vector class does, e.g.: myVec[10]=value; None of the available answers explained that. Is it not possible?

Answer (score 2):

At first... This:

```
CEntry& operator= (const CEntry& b) {
    *this = b;
    return *this;
};
```

Shouldn't work (this should result in recursive call of `operator=`).

The second thing is that you're trying to assign `CEntry *` to `CEntry`, this would work if you had `CEntry *operator=( CEntry *orig)`, but I think this is bad coding practice.

Comment: Using `CEntry *operator=( CEntry *orig)` it compiles okey, but gdb stops at `No memory available to program now: unsafe to call malloc
warning: Unable to restore previously selected frame`

Comment: @sealskej add this warning to your question and add output of `bt` (backtrace) command from gdb after fall (I hope you're using -g flag when compiling).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added `bt` to my post as you have suggested.

Comment: @sealskej I still don't see bt output, it should be something like: `#0  XS::ModuleLoader::i () at include/ModuleLoader.h:35
#1  0x000000000040e483 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe628) at src/main.cpp:37`

Comment: Okey. I am trying to find it in XCode.

Comment: @sealskej if you have console available you should be able to run: `gdb yourApp` than type `run` (inside gdb) and when application falls than `bt` :)

Comment: Okey. Thanks. Edited now in my post.

Answer (score 1):

This question may be related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168543/overloading-assignment-operator-with-subscript-operator).

I tried to fix your code; I believe that this is what you were trying to do:

> (tested this code on g++ 5.3.0)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

// Some implementation for CKey and CValue:
typedef int CKey;
struct CValue {
  int value;
  CValue(int value=0) : value(value) {}
};

class CEntry {
public:
  CKey key;
  CValue val;

  CEntry(): key(0), val(0) {}
  CEntry(const CKey& key, const CValue& val): key(key), val(val) {}

  CEntry& operator= (const CEntry& b) {
    this->key = b.key;
    this->val = b.val;
    return *this;
  };
};

class EntriesArray {    
public:
    CEntry *entries;
    int length;

  EntriesArray(int length) {
    this->length = length;
    entries = new CEntry[length];
  };

  CEntry& operator[] (const int index) {
      if (index < 1 || index > length) {
          throw std::domain_error("out of bounds!");
      }
      return entries[index - 1];
  };

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  using namespace std;

  EntriesArray a(5);

  // This works
  a.entries[0] = CEntry(CKey(1), CValue(1));
  cout << a[1].val.value << endl;

  // This doesn't work
  a[1] = CEntry(CKey(2), CValue(2));
  cout << a[1].val.value << endl;
}
```

Also you might want to use `a[1]` as `a[1].val.value` e.g.:

```
cout << a[1] << endl;
```

To do this just add to this line to cEntry:

```
operator int() { return val.value; }
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Because `EntriesArray::operator[]` returns a `CEntry &`, but `new CEntry` returns a `CEntry *`.

Perhaps you want `a[1] = CEntry(CKey(1), CValue(1))`?  (no `new`.)

---

*By the way, your current definition of `CEntry::operator=` will lead to a stack overflow.*

Comment: I have tried to return `CEntry*` in `EntriesArray::operator[]`. Seems not working as well :( Could you please post example, how to solve it?

Comment: @sealskej: Don't have it return a `CEntry *`, that would lead to ugly semantics.

Comment: This is true, but I think it'll still fail even when this is fixed. When you do a[1], 1 is > length so you'll get an ArrayOutOfBounds.

Comment: @John3136: We haven't seen how `a` has been constructed.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
return *entries[index - 1];
```

dereferences a NULL pointer.

You want the pointer itself to be overwritten by `a[1] = new CEntry(CKey(1), CValue(1));`, not the pointed-to-value.

Try this:

```
class EntriesArray
{    
public:
  int length;
  CEntry **entries;

  EntriesArray( int length ) : length(length), entries(new CEntry*[length]())
  {
  }

  // defaulted special member functions are inappropriate for this class
  EntriesArray( const EntriesArray& );          // need custom copy-constructor
 ~EntriesArray();                               // need custom destructor
  EntriesArray& operator=(const EntriesArray&); // need custom assignment-operator

  CEntry*& operator[] (const int index) {
      if (index < 1 || index > length) {
          throw ArrayOutOfBounds();
      }
      return entries[index - 1];
  }
};
```

Comment: I have tried this, but I am getting same backtrace mentioned in EDIT part of my post. Using `CEntry *operator=( CEntry *orig)`.

Comment: @sealskej: Get rid of `CEntry`'s assignment operator, the compiler-generated one should be fine.  And then try this code.

Comment: When I get rid of `CEntry`'s assignment operator, I am getting `No viable overloaded '='` by XCode on line `a[1] = new CEntry(CKey(1), CValue(1));`

Comment: @sealskej: Line 164 and 168 are not the same as what I gave you.

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comment above:
To make it work with writing new values, you probably need something like this
(I haven't double checked for off by one or ptr vs reference stuff)

```
CEntry& operator[] (const int index) {
  if (index < 1) {
      throw ArrayOutOfBounds();
  }
  // Add default elements between the current end of the list and the
  // non existent entry we just selected.
  //
  for(int i = length; i < index; i++)
  {
      // BUG is here.
      // We don't actually know how "entries" was allocated, so we can't
      // assume we can just add to it.
      // We'd need to try to resize entries before coming into this loop.
      // (anyone remember realloc()? ;-)
      entries[i] = new CEntry();
  }
  return *entries[index - 1];
};
```

Comment: No, this will just happily write past the end of the `entries` array and trash other objects' memory.

Comment: Yes, you are 100% correct. Stupid stupid stupid stupid. Allocated the objects, but didn't increase the array size to include them. Makes me think if what the OP wants is a random access 1 base array, might be better to wrap a vector or something.

Comment: I definitely agree.  But everyone has to rewrite `std::vector` at least once so they properly appreciate it.

Comment: I cant use `std::vector`, because I am doing school homework, where it is forbidden.

Comment: Maybe I will use John's solution, but overloaded subscript operator seemed more elegant for me. I need to create 1 base array, because I want to rewrite b-tree operations pseudocode, which uses 1 base array.

Comment: overloading will work, but you need to address my actual point in the above. Since you want to say a[1] = <expr>, you need to be sure that a[1] works even on an empty collection.