# how to create multiple operator overloading in c++ object oriented programming like obj[10]=3 with [] operator and = operator

Tags: c++, class, oop, operator-overloading

i have a certain class and i want to create 2 operators that will work together

like class with array and i want to change a certain index in the array

like this obj[3]=5

is this possible?
if yes,how?

this is the code i made for [] operator

```
double Polynomial::operator[](int index) const {
    int maxT = this->currentMax;
    if (index > 0 && index < this->getDegree(false))
        return this->coefficients[index];
    cout << "overflow in index";
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [overloading assignment operator With subscript operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168543/overloading-assignment-operator-with-subscript-operator)

Comment: TL;DR: `double Polynomial::operator...` --> `double &Polynomial::operator...`

Comment: While it's not _wrong_ to do bounds checking in `operator[]` it's unconventional. Most containers skip bounds checking in `operator[]` (to be as fast as possible) and provide a member function called `at()` which does bounds checking and throws an exception if `index` is out of bounds. Btw, `index` should usually be an `unsigned` type, like `size_t`. Here's a simple example to play with: https://godbolt.org/z/qr26cd

Comment: There is no **single** operator `[]=`, so you can't overload it.  You can overload the `[]` operator and the `=` operator.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I don't see operator `[]=` mentioned or implied. The title mentions  `[]` and `=` separately.

Comment: @TedLyngmo When I read the title, it didn't mention using `[]` and `=` separately.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Maybe I have my forgiving glasses on :-) "_[] operator and = operator_" sounds like "_`operator[]` and `operator=`_" to me and the implementation of `operator[]` (not `operator[]=`) also makes me think that OP knows that they are separate operators.

Answer (score 0):

Your `operator[]` is a `const` method, hence it cannot be used to modify members. Unless you want to do something fancy on assigning to an element, you don't really need some `operator=` when your `operator[]` returns a reference to the element.

As mentioned in comments, doing bounds-checking in `operator[]` is not typical. Consider that in a loop each call to `operator[]` would do bounds-checking even if the user made sure that only valid indices are used. Thats not quite efficient. So in addition to your `const` operator you can provide this one

```
double& Polynomial::operator[](size_t index)  {  // <-- no const
    return coefficients[index];
}
```

Assuming you also have a `size` method you can then write a loop:

```
for (size_t i=0; i< poly.size(); ++i) {
    poly[i] = i;
}
```

PS: `system("pause")` is a no-go, see [system("pause"); - Why is it wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong)